# how to open Tor browser tab using .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, browser, tor-browser-bundle

I have installed the Tor browser on my PC(Window 10).
Now I want to open a link in Tor browser with C#, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be simple like opening any other browser

```
Process.Start("[Full Path Here] tor.exe", "http://www.YourUrl.com");
```

Comment: that's great I have tried it and it works perfectly I have another question, I want to open URLs in the same tab rather than new tab for each URL..

Comment: @Novapex if that answers your question, then please mark it as answer. (that's how this site works). and if you have another question, then ask open another question (that's also how this site works)